# How to unset network mode in an overriding docker compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Consider a part of some base `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  foo:
    image: bar
    network_mode: host
.
.
.
```

Then, consider a `docker-compose.prod.yml` file which would override the base file's network mode and also set ports:

```
services:
  foo:
    ports:
      - 'xxxx:yyyy'
    network_mode: ?
```

I am looking for a value of `?` such that the `network_mode` is considered **unset**. In other words, setting it to `none` or `bridge` doesn't seem to work, so I want it to just *disappear*, or use a value with such an effect (I don't think there is a default).

An alternative solution to this problem is to define three docker-compose files: `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-compose.prod.yml`, and `docker-compose.dev.yml` (or something equivalent, doesn't matter). It works fine (see below), but I would rather have 2 files only, and override the dev file with the prod file, rather than the other way around (it feels more natural this way).

A working version using three files:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  foo:
    image: bar
.
.
.
```

`docker-compose.dev.yml`

```
services:
  foo:
    network_mode: host
```

`docker-compose.prod.yml`

```
services:
  foo:
    ports:
      - 'xxxx:yyyy'
```

Notes:

- All files are using docker-compose version `3`.
- The specific setup which doesn't work with `bridge` network mode in my case is a collection of three services - one for running web stuff (exposed to public), one for celery workers (internal), and one for Redis (internal). Using `bridge` in web and/or celery results in being unable to connect to the Redis service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to remove a option from former `docker-compose.yaml`, but the `bridge` really works, you may want to have a double confirm.

If we have a look for docker default network, you could see `bridge` really there, if we do not set `--net`, default docker will use `bridge`:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                     DRIVER              SCOPE
32a9a31082ae        bridge                   bridge              local
dcb12f4cc711        host                     host                local
16c73acab8c9        none                     null                local
```

I give a small example to prove it:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: python:3.7
    network_mode: host
    command: python -m http.server 9000
```

**docker-compose.prod.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    ports:
    - 10000:9000
    network_mode: bridge
```

- **docker-compose up**

  With this command, we will in fact just use `docker-compose.yaml`, at that time, if we open browser we can see could successfully visit e.g.: `http://$ip:9000`, this is because the network is `host`.
- **docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose.prod.yaml up**

  With this command, we will use 2 compose files, the latter one will override the duplicate option in the former one.

  If you open browser, you will find you can't visit `http://$ip/9000` now, you could just visit `http://$ip/10000`. This can prove that `host` loss effect, and the `bridge` override `host` successfully.

  (**NOTE**: you will have to assure `docker-compose.prod.yaml` after `docker-compose.yaml`, the sequence order is important.)

**UPDATE 20211017 based on your new comments:**

If you want to addtional visit other container in your compose, you will have to define network_mode in that target service to use the same network of source service with `network_mode: service:web`, see [network mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode):

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: python:3.7-alpine3.13
    command: python -m http.server 9000
    network_mode: host

  db:
    image: python:3.7-alpine3.13
    command: python -m http.server 8000
    network_mode: service:web
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    ports:
    - 10000:9000
    network_mode: bridge
```

Then, after up, you could use something like next to directly visit the service in db:

```
docker-compose exec web wget http://localhost:8000 -O -
```

**NOTE:**

- with `network_mode: bridge` in `web`, the `web` container nolonger use the default network which compose set up for you. As a result, you won't benifit from the auto dns setup by compose, which means in `web` you won't be able to access `db` container using the service name `db`.
- to conquer this issue, you now could let `db` container use the network of `web` explicitly with `network_mode: service:web`. This means the 2 containers now share the same network namespace, then you no need to visit `db` with service name, but to use `localhost`. In `web`, you now could access `db`'s 8000 port just with `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up. Unfortunately, `bridge` doesn't work for me, I have checked again. I have three services: web stuff, celery stuff, and Redis. If I use `bridge` on web and/or celery, I can't connect to Redis internally, but if I use nothing, everything connects just fine (and ports from web stuff are indeed exposed to the public). I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: I've also tried explicitly setting `bridge` on the Redis service, without good results.

Comment: As we specify network_mode, we won't be able to benifit from auto dns for docker-compose, so you could not visit other container with service name. As a amend, you could let the containers to use the same network namespace, see update in answer for details.

Comment: I assure you I will look at the edited solution because it looks very promising, just need a bit of time :(

Comment: Thanks for your update. Unfortunately, it seems that I can't publish ports and use your suggestion at the same time: `Cannot create container for service ...: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode`. Furthermore, it seems that if I include `depends_on: B` in service A, but include `network_mode: service:A` in service B, I also get a circular dependency warning.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

`docker-compose.prod.yml`

```
services:
    foo:
        network_mode: unset    # Can be any string other than 'host'.
        networks: [ default ]
        
        ports: [ 80:80 ]
```

## Docker Compose Default Network

This is the [default behavior](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/4d4b741d9c7f7f3cc78e5587f9db264f45888be5/loader/normalize.go#L59): if there's no `networks:` and no `network_mode:` defined for the service then it's attached to the `default` network.

Unfortunately an empty string is ignored by the YAML parser, so we can't override `network_mode:` back to `''`, what we can do is set `networks: [ default ]`, but that won't work with `network_mode: host` so what can we set `network_mode:` to?

`network_mode:` is equivalent to Docker `--network`, if we set it to a network name `networks:` will override it, so we can use any value other than `host` which apparently triggers some special behavior. It's probably a good idea to set it to something that will fail without `networks:` and avoid `default`, `bridge` or `none`.

**To restore the default behavior we need to add `default` to `networks:` and set `network_mode:` to something other than `host`.**

---

Note that `network_mode: default` is equivalent to `--network default` or `--network bridge` which uses the default *Docker* network: `bridge`, and not the default project-wide Compose network: `projectName_default`.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll have a look when I have the chance

Comment: Hey, sorry - took me some time to try this as I wasn't working with docker for a while. Not sure if there was any update in the meanwhile, but I'm getting the following:  `Cannot start service foo: network unset not found` as well as `'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined`

Comment: But it seems I can use `network_mode: ""` (empty string) just fine. It will take me some time to verify all services are reachable as expected with this network mode, but I think it will be a good lead.